# zip to exclude all .svn folders

Tags: compression, exclude

trying to exclude all .svn folders in the zipped subfolders

```
zip -urq bebe.zip * -x .svn
```

doesn't work...

Comment: [Unix zip directory but excluded specific subdirectories](https://superuser.com/q/312301/173513), [how to exclude directories and file zipping a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/371579), [How to exclude a directory when zipping files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219101/56041), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like -x works with file names and not with directories. I don't fully understand how this option works.

But I do have a solution for your question :

```
find . -type d -name .svn -prune -o -print | zip -uq bebe.zip -@
```

The `find` command excludes all directories named .svn (`-type d -name .svn -prune`) and lists all other files and folders (`-o -print`). The list is passed to zip through a pipe (`-@` option read list of files in standard input).

If you don't want to only include directories with regular files, you can use `-o -type f -print` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try `zip -urq bebe.zip * -x '*/.svn'`

Comment: no, sorry. but this one worked `zip -urq bebe.zip * -x '*/.svn/*'`

Comment: ah — yes, sorry, of course. I looked back at an example of when I’d tried it, and I’d apparently only excluded *files*, not folders. apologies!

Comment: Actually simpler than the first reply, so sticking with this one.